# SilverStripe 3: How to display the URL Segment / Page info of a DataObject

Tags: php, templates, url, silverstripe, data-objects

I'm getting all my DataObjects from a specific class and displaying them randomly on another page. I need to access the URL segment of the page they belong to. How do I do this?
I've tried, $URLSegment $UP.URLSegment $Parent.URLSegment etc which I can see why they would not work. I realise the dataobject does not have its own URL. I just need the URL of its page as this is its category.

PHP Function:

```
function Stockists()
{
$stockists = Stockist::get()->sort('RAND()');
return $stockists ? $stockists : false;
}
```

Template

```
<% loop $Stockists %>
   $Title
   $URLSegment (does not work)
<% end_loop %>
```

Comment: I'm assuming that Stockist is the data object not the page correct? What is the relationship to the page called? Is there a private $has_one=array('Page'=>'Page')  or similar in your Stockist class?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mark Guinn. 
Turned out I could use

```
$StockistArea.URLSegment
```

as yes Stockist is the data object class and has a

```
 private static $has_one = array(
    'StockistArea' => 'StockistArea'
);
```

to the StockistArea page! Hopefully this will help someone as I couldn't find anything on it.